# Building a package gives: Single file templates does not match package name

Tags: emacs, melpa

I want to update a package that originally was a single file. Now, it contains a directory with some files.

The original recipe was: `(tikz :repo "emiliotorres/tikz" :fetcher github)`
And according to [this](https://github.com/melpa/melpa#example-multiple-files-in-multiple-directories), I think the new version must be `(tikz :repo "emiliotorres/tikz" :fetcher github :files ("templates/*.el" "templates"))` .

I copy the new version of emiliotorres/tikz into the local copy of melpa/package-build and

```
make -k recipes/tikz
```

And I get this error

```
 • Building package tikz ...
Package: tikz
Fetcher: github
Source:  https://github.com/emiliotorres/tikz.git
Updating /home/emilio/temp/melpa2/working/tikz/
Single file templates does not match package name tikz
make: [Makefile:111: recipes/tikz] Error 255 (no tiene efecto)
```

Are you so kindly as to provide me any hint?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the linked [Melpa Readme](https://github.com/melpa/melpa#example-multiple-packages-in-one-repository), the following configuration should include enire directory `templates` into the package:

```
(tikz :repo "emiliotorres/tikz"
      :fetcher github
      :files ("tikz.el" "templates"))
```

An alternate approach, that eventually was chosen by the OP, also documented in `MELPA` Readme:

> If your package requires some additional files, but is otherwise fine with the defaults, it's recommended to use the special element :defaults as the very first element of the `:files` list, which causes the default value shown above to be prepended to the specified file list. For example `:files (:defaults "snippets")` would cause the "snippets" subdir to be copied in addition to the defaults.

Hence, in the context of the question:

```lisp
(tikz :repo "emiliotorres/tikz"
      :fetcher github
      :files (:defaults "templates"))
```

Comment: Thank you! The final recipe is
(tikz :repo "emiliotorres/tikz" :fetcher github
   :files (:defaults "templates"))

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. `MELPA` Reame provides quite thorough documentation, so I'm not surprised you found the working solution eventually. Anyway, I updated the answer to reflect this additional approach too.